# MYSQL: How to pass an audit sequence from the API to the triggers?

Tags: mysql, audit

I'm building a generic audit module following the idea of [this method (called as existing solution)](https://github.com/tdely/cdc_audit). The magic happens in Triggers, where the change the data is replicated into an additional audit table. Now I want to extend the existing solution and group these audit messages according to transactions and group of transactions. Here comes the table design focusing on the issue:

```
CREATE TABLE audit_transaction_groups(
    atg_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY COMMENT 'Reference for this group/type.',
    atg_short VARCHAR(1000) COMMENT 'Short description/Type', 
    atg_desc TEXT COMMENT 'html Snippet Description for Displaying only',
    atg_mode ENUM('API','MANUAL','IMPORT') COMMENT 'Type of change in the database.'
);
CREATE TABLE audit_transactions(
    a_transaction_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY COMMENT 'The one reference for different audit tables',
    atg_id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'refer to Group/Type for documentation',
    a_transaction_short VARCHAR(1000) COMMENT 'Short description if any',
    a_closed ENUM('NO','YES') NOT NULL COMMENT 'Flag showing if transaction is still in progress',
    FOREIGN KEY (atg_id) REFERENCES audit_transaction_groups(atg_id)
);
CREATE TABLE audit_sequence(
    audit_seq SERIAL PRIMARY KEY COMMENT 'Unique id=sequence overall audit tables',
    audit_error VARCHAR(1000) COMMENT 'Error messages from Audit trail, if any',
    a_transaction_id BIGINT UNSIGNED NULL COMMENT 'Reference to the transaction, if any.',
    FOREIGN KEY (a_transaction_id) REFERENCES audit_transactions(a_transaction_id)
);
```

There will be some functions or procedures in mysql to simplify the API-layer. The following check list shows the sequence of API-calls:

- BEGIN TRANSACTION
- Get or Create a transaction group (id)
- Get a transaction id with reference to the group
- get a sequence id
- One `insert`, `update` or `delete` statement with an audit trigger.
- get next audit id.
- process next `insert`, `update` or `delete` statement
- ...
- Update transaction the set it on closed.
- COMMIT;

The issue now is, how to pass the audit sequence to the audit trigger?

My first idea was to add an additional field to each table like `last_audit_seq`. With INSERT and UPDATE only an additional field, but the DELETE there it is getting complicated, unless I update this field before before deleting it.

Second idea was to use the `SET auditid = LAST_INSERT_ID();` as first statement in the trigger, but if the API/SQL-command is not following the check list, the wrong sequence is referenced. I may detect such a situation to check, if the related transaction is still open. In this case I may distinguish between an transactional modification or a wild one (without a transaction).

Are there other methods to pass the audit_seq in a save way? Especially one without modifying the data tables?

Comment: What about a combination of `UUID_SHORT()` (a 64 bit unsigned monotonic counter) for the "sequence" and a user-defined variable (which doesn't have to be "passed" because it has session scope, not program scope) to persist it, if you need to?

Comment: After checking I'm using a session variable between a procedure, called before the statement and used in the trigger. UIID_SHORT is very interesting, it made it on my 'intersting feature list'.  In my case the procedure or the trigger do an insert with a AUTOINCREMENT primary key and it is using the primary key as unique session id. Feel free to put the answer, thanks for your support.